# How do I bind a service from a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm attempting to bind a service from a fragment the same way I have done succesfully in an activity, but when I try to call a method on the service I get a NullPointerException - Obviously because the service is null. Now is there some problem with binding to the service in onStart or am I simply doing it wrong?

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LiteTrickService.class);
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(LiteTrickService.BROADCAST_ACTION));
    getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(LiteTrickService.BROADCAST_FAIL));
    getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    getActivity().unbindService(mConnection);
    getActivity().unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    mBound = false;
}
```

*edit:* Sorry. That's my mistake for not giving this question enough thought. mConnection is a ServiceConnection and looks like this :

```
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() 
{

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Stacktrace :

```
01-03 15:21:22.355: E/AndroidRuntime(12360): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 15:21:22.355: E/AndroidRuntime(12360): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 15:21:22.355: E/AndroidRuntime(12360):    at lite.hattrick.players.PlayerRankingFragment.onOptionsItemSelected(PlayerRankingFragment.java:205)
```

And this is would be the exact place where the exception is thrown : 
case POPULATE_ID:

```
        if (hasData) {
            return false;
        }
        if(!mBound)
            getActivity().bindService(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), LiteTrickService.class), mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        mService.refreshPlayers(); // Null Pointer Exception as mService is null
        pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
```

Comment: wwhat's in mConnection ? plus, post stack trace

Comment: The binding of a service is tied to a Context, so that should work.  You should show more code as I suspect the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: @jsmith I'd gladly show more code but I would need to specifically know why service would be null. I edited my original question to include the stacktrace

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem. Turns out I had forgotten to provide service declaration in my manifest with its correct package name.

by changing

```
<service android:name=".LiteTrickService" />
```

to

```
<service android:name="lite.hattrick.services.LiteTrickService" />
```

I solved the problem and the service is now connecting as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your `NullPointerException` is on the `mService` variable. As you call `bindService()`, the `Activity` binds to the `Service` on it's own thread. This means that your code will keep running while the service is binding. This results in your `mService` variable still being `null`.

What you could do is move the code that has to run after the `Service` has bound, to the `onServiceConnected()` method of your `mConnection`. This will assure that the `mService` variable will point to your service, and will not be null.

Comment: I did what you said but it would appear that the Service is never successfully connected as onServiceConnected is never called.

Comment: You should still do it, because, if your `(mBound)` variable can be `false`, then you will still get a `nullpointer` because the binding of a `Service` takes more time than you think, and as it's an asynchronous call, your subsequent call to `mService.refreshPlayers()` will give a nullpointer.

Comment: You are correct and i adjusted my code so that refreshPlayers would only be called if mBound is true.