# Bound service with Activity with Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-service

I have question about binding service. I am having parent activity and several fragments, i am binding and unbinding service with activity,now  can i get access to that service in fragment? I need to use ServiceConnection in Fragments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124632/how-do-i-bind-a-service-from-a-fragment

Comment: Bind service to the host Activity and Fragments should work with the service thought the Activity with the help of callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could access services of parent activity inside your fragments by something like this :

```
getActivity().getMyService()
```

Comment: i have added   connectionService = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), XMPPService.class);
        bindService(connectionService, this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);in my activity ....what is getMyService()

Comment: @Richa getMyService() will be your reference to the service you have created locally.You can find more details here [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample) . Hope this will clarify your query.

Answer (score 0):

===========in you activity=================

```
    callbackFragmentServiceConnection callbackfragment;
        public interface callbackFragmentServiceConnection{
            public void servicefun(MusicPlayService musicPlayService);
        }

        public void registerClientFragment(Fragment fragment){

            this.callbackfragment = (callbackFragmentServiceConnection)fragment;

        }

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {

            mBound = true;


            callbackfragment.servicefun(musicPlayService);



        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
```

=================in your fragment=============

```
public class FragmentLibraryTrack extends Fragment implements 

    MainActivity.callbackFragmentServiceConnection {


        MainActivity mainActivity;
     @Override
        public void onAttach(Context context) {
            super.onAttach(context);
            mainActivity= (MainActivity) context;


        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            mainActivity.registerClientFragment(this);

    }

    @Override
        public void servicefun(MusicPlayService musicPlayService) {
            Log.e("reached sucessfully","yes");
        }

    }
```

Comment: this is what i already have done.but cant we keep the code in activity only and acess on ServiceConnection. Because binding and unbinding in every fragment is not good idea